# Bit bucket integration with teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, bitbucket

Hello I have a repository that is hosted on bit bucket and i would like this repository to be built in teamcity as part of commit. I have set my configurations appropriately.

However i keep getting this error -> Failed to collect changes, error: List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does "Test connection" on the vcs root settings page work?

Comment: @C Kingsley : I believe your credentials are wrong. Is it git or hg repository.If you share this detail i can post an answer with a snapshot of corresponding version control setting in teamcity